# VB.Net clone hierarchy where parent has reference to child and vice versa -> circular reference

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns, circular-reference, icloneable

This is the situation:

```
Class A 
    Implements ICloneable

    Public Property Children As List(Of Child)

    Public Function Clone() As Object Implements ICloneable.Clone
        Return New A With {
            .Children = Children.Select(Function(c) DirectCast(c.Clone(), Child)).ToList()
        }
    End Function
End Class

Class Child 
    Implements ICloneable

    Public Property Parent As A

    Public Function Clone() As Object Implements ICloneable.Clone
        Return New Child With {
            .Parent = DirectCast(Parent.Clone(), A)
        }
    End Function
End Class
```

The actual object is more complex, having several levels.
I'm not sure how to solve this because, at the moment, whenever you call `Clone` on the parent `A` class, you will end up with a circular reference.

How can I avoid this situation? Should I create my own `Clone` function and pass along a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to just have the `Child` class not clone the `Parent` property at all.  When a `Child` clones itself, it could either leave the `Parent` property the same, or just leave it null.  For instance:

```
Class Child 
    Implements ICloneable

    Public Property Parent as A

    Public Function Clone() As Object Implements ICloneable.Clone
        Return New Child() With { .Parent = Me.Parent }
    End Function
End Class
```

Then, when the parent `A` class clones itself, it could set the `Parent` property of all the cloned children, like this:

```
Class A 
    Implements ICloneable

    Public Property Children As List(Of Child)

    Public Function Clone() As Object Implements ICloneable.Clone
        Return New A() With 
            {
            .Children = Me.Children.Select(
                Function(c)
                    Dim result As Child = DirectCast(c.Clone(), Child))
                    result.Parent = Me
                    Return result
                End Function).ToList()
            }
    End Function
End Class
```

Alternatively, as you suggested, you could make your own `Clone` method which takes the parent object as a parameter:

```
Class Child 
    Public Property Parent as A

    Public Function Clone(parent As A) As Object
        Return New Child() With { .Parent = parent }
    End Function
End Class
```

It won't implement `ICloneable`, but as long as you don't need it to be interchangeable with other types of `ICloneable` objects, then that won't matter.  Similarly, you could just overload your constructor:

```
Class Child 
    Public Property Parent as A

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(childToClone As Child, parent As A)
        ' Copy other properties from given child to clone
        Me.Parent = parent
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks Steven. While I did solve this another way (the object was fundamentally changed), your solution would be a good approach.